# static library fails to init mlmodel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, coreml

I want to load my model inside my library (.a)

The init is trying to load the compiled mlmodel from the app bundle, but the bundle contains the path of the application compiling the library not the other way around

```
>     convenience init() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: TinyYOLO.self)
        let assetPath = bundle.url(forResource: "TinyYOLO", withExtension:"mlmodelc")
        try! self.init(contentsOf: assetPath!)
    }
```

Can't seem to find any related issue.

The setup is classic, an objective-c project (with react-native) embedding multiple xcodeproj as libraries (the model is loaded in swift though), i assume the hacky workaround would be to include the compiled model with a modified class to load it but that seems dirty.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do not remove related tag on build related issues !

Comment: "from the bundle". Which bundle? The app bundle?

Comment: app bundle yes, it's weird

Comment: How is the model actually included in the bundle? Is the assetPath actually non-nil?

Comment: The model is in the library, so yeah the assetPath is nil since the model is not in the app bundle (and it shouldn't be ?). Easy fix is to include the model in the app but that would defeat the purpose :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, addressing what you wrote in the comments here for the larger space.

static libraries cannot contain non-code assets. The only way would be through "trickery" of making the byte data for you asset a `uint8_t *` (other other appropriate data type) symbol within the .a. And by doing this, you'd be referencing memory (via that symbol) versus a file. Obviously not ideal for many reasons.

You have a couple of approaches you can take:

- Directly add the items into app bundle.
- If you are using Xcode to build your .a, create a bundle for the assets while building the .a. And then include that bundle into the app.

I currently do the latter for my game engine, where I have embedded fonts (like debug fonts) and other assets that the engine requires. Note that regardless, you're having to add the individual assets or the bundle to the app (app's bundle). However, with the later, you are only adding one item.

Any bundle references you have then are to that bundle. The way I've handled that was to have a fallback system where I can point my code to bundles in use. Then it goes down the chain to find the assets I need.

Comment: I am already using the first option (just adding a reference is enough) since using the second (i actually researched that but i figured i could find something better/easier ) would be too much of a hassle for what i am doing. What amazes me is that there seems to be no easy way to do something that should be really easy (pretty sure with a framework in a swift project it is working out of the box), feels like i'm back in the 90's

Comment: Well, you are using a static lib, which is "older" technology.

Comment: Yeah i had some issues on react-native, people from facebook and google using objective-c and static libs everywhere so 3rd will follow suit, really annoying.